# mysql fulltext is there a way to select relevance as a column?

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search

I would like to know if there is a way I can select the relevance score as a column? So I can store for later manipulation

Also is there any way (for trouble shooting) to determine why a row got a relevance? or what words matched. For example when I use `WITH QUERY EXPANSION` I am getting results and I do not know why they match.

Comment: `WITH QUERY EXPANSION` is usually useless, unless you have a collection of _very_short_ sentences. You can examine some weights with the command line utility `myisam_ftdump`, but that's about it as 'debugging' goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re 1) yes. See the [examples in the mySQL docs:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

```
mysql> SELECT id, body, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
    -> ('Security implications of running MySQL as root') AS score
    -> FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
    -> ('Security implications of running MySQL as root');
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
| id | body                                | score           |
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
|  4 | 1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ... | 1.5219271183014 |
|  6 | When configured properly, MySQL ... | 1.3114095926285 |
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Re 2) No, not to my knowledge.

Check out the comments on the manual pages, there are several gotchas that may explain why one is getting zero results on a query that should return more than that.